# Do you need a CAL if I'm only logging in as a local administrator on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, licensing, cals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

Here the scenario:  I'm helping a really small business (less than 10 employees, no real administrators) migrate over an older sql server installation to a new box with new hardware.

We would like the new box to run on Windows Server 2008 R2, either Foundation or Standard (whichever is most cost-effective).  I know that for the Sql Server install we could either buy a per processor license or just use Sql Server Express.  The box would only have Sql Server running on it and maybe one other non microsoft service with non microsoft login.

There are a few services that connect to the Sql Server instance from other boxes (web server, other services, employees directory connecting using sql server manager).  All of the services connect using sql server accounts, not windows accounts.  In fact there are not any "domain" accounts at all.

Since the company doesn't have any real administrators the only way any person would login to the Server box is either directly onto the box as a local administrator or within the companies own internal network using RDP.

I'm trying to determine how many CALs (if any) we need to purchase.

Comment: sorry this is one of those licensing questions best answered by the vendor

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, I assume your question includes Windows Server AND Windows SQL Server licensing.
For Windows Server Licensing, you need to have license for Windows Server OS and CAL for device/user connecting.Whether you choose to select per device or per user licenses depends on your environment.
For SQL 2008, similarly, you need to have server and CAL licenses.However, you have a choise of buying expensive per processor licence that covers unlimited amount of CALs, or you can buy reasonably cheap base license and add as many client CALs for users/devices as you need.Normally per processor license is aquired for the envirnment exposed to the internet where amount of users is unknown.
As for SQL Express, I suggest you check it's limitations (i.e. database size) to see if they could be limiting your application growth.